# Generics polymorphism in GWT

Tags: generics, gwt

```
class ModelImpl extends Model {
```

...

```
CellTable<? extends Model> tableImpl;
```

...

```
tableImpl=new CellTable<ModelImpl>();
```

...

and finally 
...

```
    TextColumn<ModelImpl> column = new TextColumn<ModelImpl>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(ModelImpl object) {
        return object.getColumnValue();
      }
    };
    tableImpl.addColumn(column, "nameColumn");
```

compiler says:

> cannot find symbol method
>   addColumn(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.TextColumn < ModelImpl > ,java.lang.String)

but ModelImpl extends Model!! Whats happening?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have defined `tableImpl` with the type `CellTable<? extends Model>`.

`? extends Model` means "some specific subclass of Model, but I am not sure what it is".

`addColumn` has the signature:

```
public void addColumn(Column<T,?> col)
```

The problem is, the you have lost what `T` is, because tableImpl is of type `CellTable<? extends Model>`.  `addColumn` only takes a column of the exact same kind of T that the CellTable is parameterized by (in your case ModelImpl). But you have stored your CellTable in a variable that does not know what that exact type is.

So change `tableImpl`'s definition to look like:

```
CellTable<ModelImpl> tableImpl;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I, your solution is not polymorphic, I want to write tableImpl=new CellTable<ModelImpl3>(); and <pre>tableImpl=new CellTable<ModelImpl4>();. I thought that somehow ... polymorphic

Comment: @XXTerror In that case, you could make a new class that has a generic type argument 'T extends Model' and extends TextColumn<T>, then overrides getValue(). Then construct one of those instead of the anonymous TextColumn. You still need to change the type of tableImpl though.

Comment: @XXTerror your code that initializes the field and the one that adds columns are tihtly linked. So either you use a local variable of the more specific type (if they're in the same method, or you parameterize the whole class with some "T extends Model"